# how to aggregate values in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

here is my xml  :

```
<countries>
   <country>
      <name> .....</name>
      <capital>....</capital>
      <continent>....</continent>
   </country>
   .
   .
   .(a lot of countries)..
<countries>
```

and i created an html table with 2columns (using xslt) , representing the name and the capital for each country . but now i want to create a table for each continent , and each table contains the list of all countries belonging to that continent , and i have no idea how to proceed ! thanks for your help!
here is a quick view of my XSLT :

```
<table border="3" width="100%" align="center">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Capital</th>
</tr>

<xsl:for-each select="countries/country">
<tr>
<td >
    <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
</td>
<td>
<xsl:value-of select="capital"/>
</td>
</tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: for xslt 1.0 see http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this **XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:key name="Continent" match="country" use="continent"/>

    <xsl:template match="countries">
        <countries>
            <xsl:for-each
                select="//country[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('Continent', continent)[1])]">
                <continent><xsl:value-of select="continent"/></continent>
                <table border="3" width="100%" align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Capital</th>
                    </tr>

                    <xsl:for-each select="key('Continent', continent)">
                        <tr>
                            <td >
                                <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="capital"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>

                </table>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </countries>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XSLT 1.0** See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZXVEE

**XSLT 2.0** See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/naZXVEE/1